# How can a player character cause the stunned condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions

Besides the monk's class feature “Stunning Strike”, how can a player character cause the stunned condition? I am looking for a solution other than very rare or legendary magic items or any Unearthed Arcana. Spells or other class features are ideal.

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve here that we might be able to help with? Why do you care about stunning specifically?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose There is no specific reason. I just play a monk often and the DM hates it when I stun her monsters. So I want to know how else I can do it if I don't play a monk.

Comment: @Eternallord66 as you said, the DM dislikes you stunning her monsters, not you being a monk. Why are you looking for other ways to stun monsters, and by extension annoy your DM?

Comment: @PixelMaster It is more of a game to annoy her. We all do it and she does it to us. Even her husband does it to her. It keeps our games interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 5 spells, the Monk's Stunning Strike, and a few items.

The only ways, disregarding items, to stun a creature are the Monk's [Stunning Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#ClassFeatures) (PHB):

> The target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or be stunned until the end of your next turn

The [Contagion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion) (PHB) spell:

> In addition, whenever the creature takes damage, it is
>   stunned until the end of its next turn.

The [Divine Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divine-word) (PHB) spell:

> 30 hit points or fewer: blinded, deafened, and stunned
>   for 1 hour

The [Psychic Scream](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/psychic-scream) (XGtE, 163) spell:

> On a failed save, a target takes 14d6 psychic damage and is stunned.

The [PW: Stun](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/power-word-stun) (PHB) spell:

> If the target has 150 hit points or fewer, it is stunned.

The [Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol) (PHB) spell:

> Each target must make a Wisdom saving throw and becomes stunned for 1 minute on a failed save.

Including items, the DMG lists the Legendary Hammer of Thunderbolts, the very rare Robe of Scintillating Colors, the very rare Staff of Thunder and Lightning, the rare Wand of Wonder (only stuns you, though), and the legendary Whelm.

The Princes of the Apocalypse book also has an uncommon [Storm Boomerang](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/storm-boomerang) that stuns (credit to NautArch for finding this):

> On a hit, the boomerang deals 1d4 bludgeoning Dmg and 3d4 thunder Dmg, and the target must succeed on a DC 10 CON saving throw or be stunned until the end of its next turn.

Comment: Items that are not legendary or very rare items are ok.

Comment: Note that the *contagion* stun effect is only if you pick Slimy Doom, and (per the errata for that spell) the target has to fail three saves against the spell to acquire any of the disease effects.

Answer (score 4):

## There are plenty of (high-level) spells that cause this condition

Many stun abilities come from spells (ranging from 5th to 9th), including:

- [*contagion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion)
- [*divine word*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divine-word)
- [*symbol*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)
- [*psychic scream*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/psychic-scream) (XGtE, p. 163)
- [*power word stun*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/power-word-stun)

A list of all spells that inflict the stunned condition, and one that removes it, can be found [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-condition=14&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=).

Comment: I think the most obvious spell is *Power Word Stun*, don't you agree? ;)

Comment: There are only 6 spells on that list, you should probably just list them out since you already started.

Comment: There's only five spells on that list that *inflict* the Stunned condition - one of them heals it.